# Is it possible to do a queue alternative with list in python

Tags: python, list, queue

I am just wondering if I can make the queue functions with list-
for example, here is some functions in list which simulates queue:

```
def newqueue():
    return list()

def empty(q):
    if len(q)==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

is it possible to create all the queue commands (or at least the basic ones) with lists?
I want it too to work like queue- it means that you, for example, put the entry to the first place(0), and take it from the last entry(the biggest place (3 for example with 4 entries list))

Comment: Anything specific that you have in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queue can be made just using `list` in Python!

```
# Initializing a queue 
queue = [] 

# Adding elements to the queue 
queue.append('a') 
queue.append('b') 
queue.append('c') 

print("Initial queue") 
print(queue) 

# Removing elements from the queue 
print("\nElements dequeued from queue") 
print(queue.pop(0)) 
print(queue.pop(0)) 
print(queue.pop(0)) 

print("\nQueue after removing elements") 
print(queue)
```

```
Initial queue
deque(['a', 'b', 'c'])

Elements dequeued from the queue
a
b
c

Queue after removing elements
deque([])
```

Comment: In queue, every entry comes after the last one. And first one in is first one out.  that is what is happening here, can you please elaborate what are you looking for?

Comment: So this is what you wanted? I am confused!

Comment: So is your query solved? Or do you have specific functionality in mind?